# Or operators in PHP

Tags: php

can anyone advise what i'm doing wrong here?

I'm trying to load a jQuery function IF the page isn't using a template OR if it's not a single OR if it's not an archive.

I have the below...

```
<?php if ( ! is_page_template('modelPages.php') || ! is_archive() || ! is_single ) { ?>
```

But it doesn't seem to work... HOWEVER if I remove the or operators and subsequent rules, the function doesn't load (which is correct) on the modelPage.php templates.

How should i be writing this rule?

Thanks

Comment: This isn't a WordPress question - should be moved over to SO.

Comment: You're missing a set of parenthesis from your `is_single` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<?php if ( (! is_page_template('modelPages.php')) || (! is_archive()) || (! is_single) ) { ?>
```

Think your 'not' ! is causing the issue. 
btw, you could move it to this

```
<?php if ( !( is_page_template('modelPages.php') || is_archive() || is_single() ) ) { ?>
```